# How to get the version of wsgi_mod which apache used?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am using ubuntu 12.041 and installed apache through apt-get.

I don't know what version of mod_wsgi i am using albeit I google about it.
All I found is you can use apachctl to restart you apache and you would get 
something like "Apache/2.2.2 (Unix) mod_wsgi/1.0 Python/2.3 configured". But 
this's not happened to me.

Is there any way to know what version I am using ? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your WSGI application look at the value of `mod_wsgi.version` in the WSGI environ dictionary. That or `import mod_wsgi` module in a WSGI application running under mod_wsgi (not command line Python) and print out `mod_wsgi.version` from that module.

Comment: some... code? or a folder? or a pointer to something that made this an easy 1,2,3 process would be really really useful.

Comment: Just add `import mod_wsgi` and `logsomewhere(mod_wsgi.version)` to your code. As mentioned, you need to run the code within wsgi/apache. Not inside Django Runserver. Or you add `modwsgi.version` to a template Context and show it on some system information page of your appliaction.

Answer (score 20):

If you restart Apache and inspect the log:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
tail -n 5 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

... you should see the version:

> [Fri Jun 05 15:13:46.546029 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2245]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 ***mod_wsgi/3.4***
>   Python/3.4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: I believe the information in that line may be able to be excluded in part if Apache is configured a certain way. So don't necessarily rely on the information about mod_wsgi and Python appearing.

Comment: You can look at the existing log without restarting: `grep mod_wsgi /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 13):

I use this

```
dpkg -l | grep wsgi
```

I don't know what it is doing, but it is a version?

As an aside that is probably not right, the version i have -

```
libapache2-mod-wsgi  (on ubuntu 10.04)
```

is *not* python 3.x compliant. How I know that is a mystery - some random web forum. Also, how you'd actually work out which version is in the libapache2 version is *beyond* my ken.

But, ah, that unix script above will get the version for you. You're on your own after that, sailor.

Comment: For more detail on mod_wsgi version of distro packaged version, from scribbled notes I have, you can run ``apt-cache policy libapache2-mod-wsgi``. A Python 3 version will have 'py3' as part of the package name on Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 9):

move to apache modules directory where mod_wsgi.so is.

run the following commands.

```
$ strings mod_wsgi.so | grep -w -A 1 "wsgi_init"
wsgi_init
4.5.7
```

*Note* it may be necessary to use `-A` with more than `1` line displayed after the occurrence of `wsgi_init`. For example with mod_wsgi version 2.7.5 you need `-A 2` to see the version number:

```
$ strings mod_wsgi.so | grep -w -A 2 "wsgi_init"
wsgi_init
mod_wsgi/%s
2.7.5
```

Comment: I think I am using `mod_wsgi` for Python `2.7` or `3.4.3` (trying to figure it out) and following your command did not do the trick for me. I got these two lines for output: `wsgi_init` and `mod_wsgi/%s`. There were no leading or trailing spaces in the output, only a newline separator.

Comment: I had the same issue. I changed ```-A 1``` to ```-A 5``` to get more lines after ```wsgi_init``` printed. I got ```wsgi_init
mod_wsgi/%s
2.7.5
%s.%d.%d.%d.sock
%s.%d.%d.%d.lock
sysvsem```

Answer (score 4):

A side question was about the version of Python used by `mod_wsgi`.  For that just inspect `mod_wsgi.so` modules with `ldd`:

```
➜  / cd usr/lib/apache2/modules 
➜  modules ldd mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcaabf3000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f4e29c62000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4e29a45000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4e2967b000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4e29461000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4e2925d000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f4e2905a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4e28d51000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4e2a423000)
➜  modules
```

In my case, it is clearly compiled with `python2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but I'm not seeing the answer i found so:

```
yum list installed '*mod_wsgi*'
```

or better yet

```
yum list '*mod_wsgi*'
```

to see what you have installed as well as available (perhaps) later versions.